# SnipeIt using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, asset-management

the URL section in the image attached says -

[" Uh oh! Snipe-IT thinks your URL is http://127.0.0.1:8082, but your real URL is http://app_url_placeholder/setup Please update your APP_URL settings in your .env file "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNcoI.png)

the .yml file is -
[this is the .yml file in docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhRa6.png)

I am unable to understand what is going wrong with snipe-it - that it is not working on the local host and says- **"Uh oh! Snipe-IT thinks your URL is http://127.0.0.1:8082, but your real URL is http://app_url_placeholder/setup Please update your APP_URL settings in your .env file "**

I have been trying to find the solution since hours - please can I get some help on this.

**Reference for the .yml file -
https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-snipe-it**

---

The solution to the above problem is - just small modification to the .yml file

[the Correct .yml file for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifdEL.png)